# Can't call function from included php file

Tags: php

Want to call function from included php. I do:

```
<?php
include 'http://localhost:9090/myapp-backend/login.php';
$lg = new Login();
$lg->login();
?>
```

login.php:

```
<?php
class Login
{
    public function login () {  
        //*some code
    }
}
```

End error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Login' not found in D:\xampp\htdocs\myapp\index.php on line 3
```

When i not use class in `login.php` just a function i get error that function not exists.
Whats wrong?

Comment: If it is coming from localhost, why are you attempting to include it via HTTP instead of its file path?

Comment: If this is running on a dev Windows box I'm 99% certain it won't work - you can't include files over HTTP.

Comment: Open http://localhost:9090/myapp-backend/login.php in your browser, what do you get? PHP gets exactly the same...!

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Why i can't do this? Php not allow this?

Comment: @KliverMax PHP allows you to include a remote file if correctly configured, and if you have a good reason to do so, but it will _execute_ the file and return the result to the include.  If you need to retrieve a remote PHP file (yours is _not_ remote), it can be done by other means but is _really_ not recommended.

Comment: Okay. I see that only way use window paths....

Comment: But any way i have error `no such file or directory`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To ensure it's cross-platform compatible (using PHP 5 with the constant `__DIR__`) you could use something more like this (although, I'd tend to also use `require_once` for a file like this than include).

```
//assuming you're calling the include from the a file at the root of the web server
include realpath( __DIR__ . '/myapp-backend/login.php' );

//or using require_once
require_once realpath( __DIR__ . '/myapp-backend/login.php' );
```

Although Windows is pretty flippant about using '/' or '' as directory separators anyway.

See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php

For older versions of PHP (that have the `__FILE__` constant but not the `__DIR__` constant) you can use the following - but really, this shouldn't be necessary any more:

```
require_once realpath( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/myapp-backend/login.php' );
```

See: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php

Answer (score 3):

`include` of remote file will include only *result* (that is produced by remote server), and not *source* of your code.

Use `include` locally (local FS) to get source - since you're referring to localhost

Answer (score -1):

You must use a path in your system, not a virtual directory.
E.g.:

```
include 'C:/myapp-backend/login.php';
```

Comment: Not work `require 'C:/xampp/htdocs/myapp-backend/glogin.php';` give me `no such file or directory`

Comment: Did you write `glogin.php`?